# Problem registering protobuf serializer on a certain type with kryo in flink (scala)

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, apache-flink, kryo

I have a code snippet as follows:

```
env.getConfig.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(classOf[EventMeta], classOf[ProtobufSerializer[EventMeta]])
```

where `EventMeta` is a case class generated from proto message by scalaPB. We use flink 1.10.1 and scala 2.11.

I tried to translate the Java code from the doc: `env.getConfig.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(EventMeta.class, ProtobufSerializer.class)`, but the compiler keeps telling me:

```
 overloaded method value registerTypeWithKryoSerializer with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: Class[_],x$2: Class[_ <: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer[_]])Unit <and>
[error]   [T <: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer[_] with java.io.Serializable](x$1: Class[_], x$2: T)Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (Class[com.here.lanes.laneroadreference.derivation.statefun.state.EventMeta.EventMeta], Class[org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.common.protobuf.ProtobufSerializer[com.here.lanes.laneroadreference.derivation.statefun.state.EventMeta.EventMeta]])
[error]     env.getConfig.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(classOf[EventMeta], classOf[ProtobufSerializer[EventMeta]])
```

Apparently, `ProtobufSerializer` doesn't extend `Serializer` in our version of flink. Is there an error in doc or `ProtobufSerializer`? How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Gagan No, I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing this:

```
import com.twitter.chill.protobuf.ProtobufSerializer;
```